# Javascript: How to handle undefined parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using a twitter api to get information about tweets. My code is using this information. Sometimes does it happen, that the api delivers an 'undefinded' and my code stops.

My idea was to check the parameters and only work with those who are okay:

```
if ( typeof data.id_str.user.name === 'undefined' || data.id_str.user.name === null ){ 
  next(); 
} else{
    return data.id_str.user.name;
}
```

But my check doesn't matter. If I execute the code the TypeError still happens sometimes: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". Do you have an idea what I could do to handle this error and check the next tweet?

data is not defined. But I don't know, when data will not be defined. I need a way to skip the data and use the next defined data.

I have implemented your suggests. The error appears now for the else part of the if condition. Why? And how could it work?

```
if ( typeof data && data.id_str && data.id_str.user && data.id_str.user.name === 'undefined' || data && data.id_str && data.id_str.user && data.id_str.user.name === null ){
              console.log('data.id_str.user.name is undefined. --> Why?');              
            } else {
              console.log('on User  : '+data.id_str.user.name);
              }
```

Comment: The error indicates `user` is not defined.  Check to see if `data.id_str.user` is undefined, instead of `data.id_str.user.name`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, any of the chain of `data` may be undefined, e.g. `data.id_str` may be undefined or `data.id_str.user` may be undefined. The latter case will cause:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

There are several ways to handle this such as checking each individual piece in the chain `data && data.id_str && data.id_str.user` or wrapping the retrieval in `try`/`catch`.

Comment: I know, that something in data.id_str.user.name is undefined. Do I need to know, which part is undefined? I only like to check, if anything in it is undefined. In this case I would like to go to the next tweet.

Comment: @NewbieXXL in that case using `try`/`catch` is probably the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'guarding'. Do like: `typeof data && data.id_str && data.id_str.user && data.id_str.user.name === "undefined"`
Simple sollution but helps to not lock code.

Edit: here I have found you more described example of such guarding against undefined: [Guarding against undefined parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451213/guarding-against-undefined-parameters)

Comment: thx, Pawel. Do I need to know, which part is undefined? I only like to check, if something in it is undefined. In this case I would like to go to the next tweet, check it and in best case use the output.

Comment: In this sollution you not need to know as long you are guarding against undefined from data object to name parameter. As you see && it requires every element not to be undefined. In my opinion you can avoid your comparision, just do `if (data && data.id_str && data.id_str.user && data.id_str.user.name) return data.id_str.user.name`

Comment: It just works partly. The error appaers now in another line of code. Strangely, the else part of if code is executed, that shouldn't be.

Comment: I guess you have to refactor your code then and check carefully process of your program. You can use webstorm to debug (works quite nice with debugging). Or if you are not afraid of console go node debug.